# Using pluck with maximum

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to chain options when using maximum?

I have a PhoneStats class and I want to pull the name from a few columns who have the maximum value in the table. For example if I run

```
PhoneStat.maximum('calls')
```

I get the value I expect but I would like to get maximum value as well as the id of the user in that record. Is it possible to use pluck or collect for something like this?

Thanks spickermann

Thanks. Below got me exactly what I needed.

```
PhoneStat.order('calls DESC').pluck(:name).first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write this a bit more detailed:

```
PhoneStat.order('calls DESC').first
```

Comment: Thanks. Below got me exactly what I needed.

    PhoneStat.order('calls DESC').pluck(:name).first